# how to ensure ctdocument attribute sequence in apache poi xwpf

Tags: java, xml, apache, apache-poi, xwpf

EDIT[FIX] - see at bottom.

MS office genrates this element in all documents with some underlying knowledge that the NS constraints must be enforced to a degree...

MS document example:

```
<w:document
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
    <!--whatever-->
</w:document>
```

POI output example

```
<w:document
mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
    <!--whatever-->
</w:document>
```

Notice the MC:IGNORABLE element is shifted ... Manually modifying this element inside the docx archive itself "fixes" an error thrown off by the MSOffice program which specifies an error in line 2, column 0.

So far i've tried:

```
xwpfDocument.getDocument().getDomNode()
```

^ have tried modifying, deleting and adding attributes in correct order... does not work as the shift seems to happen somewhere in the XWPFDocument.write() procedure.

I've also tried extracting the document.xml file from the docx archive, modifying it and injecting it back into the archive ... and this doesn't seem to work... CRC issues...

Is there a way to access the OPCPackage or part or anything to allow direct invocation of a built in "recalculateAttributesRelativeToNS" in this element?

... or as an alternative.. how do i automate dom changes in the document xml file inside the archive and still ensure ms compatibility?

[EDIT: "XY"]

This behavior is evident in the following scenario:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
XWPFPicture picture = imageRun.addPicture(fis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, path, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(290));
```

Document opens fine. issue not present.

The addition of this line (i know it's not technically correct, however the error should not be reported at line 2- column 0, as it should be reported further down the xml) screws everything up.

```
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().addNewEffectLst().addNewOuterShdw().setBlurRad(10000);
```

With the addition of this line, the w:document attributes change into state 2 (the poi example) hereby triggering ms Office's MS schema NS invalidation routine.

The attributes are correct. The order is wrong. Manually moving the mc:ignorable attribute to the end of the attribute list solves the issue and the document loads without issues.

This is most likely due to the fact that (in the correct implementation) the xmlns:mc attribute is preceeding the mc:ignorable attribute in the attribute list whereas in the poi output it does not (mc:Ignorable is the first element in the list).

hence... the question.

additionally... the import list:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1;
```

everything in this class is self-contained.

EDIT [FIX]

The fix consists of adding the second line in this snippet.

```
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().addNewEffectLst().addNewInnerShdw().setBlurRad(Units.toEMU(3));
picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getEffectLst().getInnerShdw().addNewPrstClr().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STPresetColorVal.BLACK);
```

Thanks again, @AxelRichter.

Comment: I believe this is [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Me and thousands other users of `apache poi` have created `*.docx` files using `apache poi` without having that problem. So I suspect the problem is somewhere outside `apache poi`. Please do providing the simplest `*.docx` source file and the simplest `apache poi` code which produces that file corruption. And please do describing your environment. What `apache poi` version is used? What `Java` version is used? What additional `Java` libraries, especially for creating `XML`, are involved?

Comment: @AxelRichter question updated with additional details.

Comment: POI version 3.17; JDK 1.8.102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointing on line 2 column 0 in the error is misleading. If you look at `/word/document.xml` then there are only 2 lines at all. The XML declaration in line 1 and all the other XML in line 2.

Your problem is that the schema definition of `CT_OuterShadowEffect` is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_OuterShadowEffect">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:group ref="EG_ColorChoice" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:attribute name="blurRad" type="ST_PositiveCoordinate" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="dist" type="ST_PositiveCoordinate" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="dir" type="ST_PositiveFixedAngle" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="sx" type="ST_Percentage" use="optional" default="100%"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="sy" type="ST_Percentage" use="optional" default="100%"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="kx" type="ST_FixedAngle" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="ky" type="ST_FixedAngle" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="algn" type="ST_RectAlignment" use="optional" default="b"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="rotWithShape" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

As you see, the `EG_ColorChoice` must occur 1 times. In other words: There must be a color setting for the `CTOuterShadowEffect`.

Following code works for me:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class WordInsertPicturesWithShadow {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

  run.setText("The picture: ");

  InputStream in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  XWPFPicture picture = run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(100));
  in.close();  

  picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().addNewEffectLst().addNewOuterShdw().setBlurRad(50000);
  //picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw().setDist(100000);
  //picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw().setDir(2700000);
  //picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw().setAlgn(
  // org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STRectAlignment.TL);
  //picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw().setRotWithShape(false);
  picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw().addNewPrstClr().setVal(
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STPresetColorVal.BLACK);

  run.setText(" text after the picture.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @AxelRichter. ... weirdly enough the document opens after the manual intervention which lead me to believe that was the underlying issue. I didn't even bother implementing the missing color.

Comment: @EverNight: Well this could be a "using tools which wants to be smarter than good" problem. Seems the tool you are using for editing XML validates the XML against a schema, if one exists. And seems it has a `*.xsd` for name space `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main`. So it removes the XML code `<a:outerShdw blurRad="10000"/>` because this violates the schema. So any kind of editing would lead to "repairing".

Comment: I think the question was misleading... either that or i don't see your trail of thought. However, for integrity reasons i should clarify that i began editing the document.xml file as an effort to fix the error caused by the addition of a  "OuterShdw" object which in that state violated the schema as you pointed out since i only added the blur effect without the color. The fix was to add the color as well. question updated with fix.