# How to pass dependency B to A if B depends upon C but C is created within A?

Tags: java, oop

I have an object A used to replace text sequences in a given Word document. To construct A, the following dependency has to be passed to its constructor:

- ReplaceBehaviour: an implementation of an abstract Visitor (Design Pattern) used to replace
  different types of content (e.g., text, images, tables) in the Word document

A internally uses ApachePOI to process Word documents. The replacement logic is defined in the Visitor implementation (B) which is passed as a dependency to A. However, to perform the replacement, B also requires C. In terms of ApachePOI, C is a XWPFDocument (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html). Executing the replaceContent method of A, three things happen in the following order:

1. A instantiates a new XWPFDocument (C) based upon the input file path of the Word document
2. A assigns C to the visitor B
3. Visitor is executed on the objects that should be replaced

If I am correct, A is a Facade (GoF design pattern), because it provides an "easier" interface to replace content in the Word document. A is considered "easier", because it encapsulates the entire Apache-POI related code. However, A internally creates the XWPFDocument C and (also internally) assigns it to the Visitor B. I am not sure if assigning C to the Visitor before executing B is considered good practice? If not, how can we solve this in a better way? Alternatively, one could construct C and B, assign C to B and then pass both of them to A on construction. But then, a client using A would have to instantiate a ApachePOI-class (XWPFDocument) him/herself which defeates the purpose of the Facade. The following pseudo code summarizes the problem described above:

```
public class A {

   private IReplaceVisitor b;

   public A(IReplaceVisitor b) {
      this.b = b;
   }      

   public void replaceContent(List<ReplacementObject> objectsToReplace, String inputWordPath, String outputWordPath) {
      XWPFDocument c = new XWPFDocument(inputWordPath);
      b.setDocument(c);
      foreach act in objectsToReplace execute act.accept(b);
      // write updated XWPFDocument c to disk
   }

}

// use of A somewhere else ...
public void testReplacement(List<ReplacementObject> objectsToReplace) {
   IReplaceVisitor b = new ConreteReplaceVisitor();
   A a = new A(b);
   a.replaceContent(objectsToReplace, "input Word path", "destination path of the updated Word 
   document");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uh... no idea what you're trying to explain there, or why you're overcomplicating this (or at least that's what it seems to me).

This what my docx generators use:

```
       for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : xdoc.getParagraphs()) {
            // simple run data text replace...
            for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                String text = run.getText(0);
                if (text != null) {
                    for (DOC_FLAGS value : DOC_FLAGS.values()) {
                        if (text.contains(value.name())) {
                            System.out.println(text);
                            System.out.println(value.value);
                            text = text.replace(value.name(), value.value);
                            run.setText(text, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're right. It sounds complicated. Please give me one more try. Your code is fine. I am already using it to replace strings in the document. That's fine. However, I also have to replace images and add tables dynamically. These other replacements need different Apache POI classes. For instance, to do something with tables XWPFTable is used instead XWPFRun. This is why I used the Visitor. It contains one method visit for each type of replaceable object (there is the base type as shown in my pseudo code. On top of that, there a concreations for images, text, tables...

Comment: I know what your goal is. my solution is pretty generic as well, but is based on what i've seen in the document.xml inside the docx which has different xml structure hierarchies for pretty much everything. i.e. there' sa difference between what you need to go through to create a correct piece of text in a table, and one in a paragraph... or a caption for an image. After wasting time trying to come up with what you;re doing and going through reflection logic, i was running out of time enoough to have to implement most the "addTable" and "addImage" routines manually based on that document.xml.

Comment: The best way technically to do what you want to do would be to create a method that figures out which constructor to call at which point based on the schemas on which the document.xml is reliant on. I used reflection for this but the aforementioned solution was adopted due to the fact that it's way less of a pain in the ass to debug.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it helped me. I was overcomplicating it. 
Using your strategy made it simpler. Once again, thank you for your effort.

Comment: here, have a bonus for being a good sport since most people don't bother marking answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286216/how-to-ensure-ctdocument-attribute-sequence-in-apache-poi-xwpf

Axel's code contains everything you need if you want to jazz up the pictures you insert with some tasty shadows :)